# OCaml - Printing recursive fatorial function return value not working

Tags: function, recursion, ocaml, factorial

I have this code:

```
let n = read_int()
let rec fact n = if n=0 then 1 else n*fact(n-1)
let () = Printf.printf "%d factorial is %d.\n" n fact(n)
```

I compile and then the compiler says:

```
File "fat.ml", line 3, characters 23-46:
Error: This expression has type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       but an expression was expected of type
         ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
         CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
       Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit
```

How can I print the returned value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is a missing parenthesis around `fact n`:

```
let () = Printf.printf "%d factorial is %d.\n" n (fact n)
```

works.

The reason behind the complicated type error that you got is that the compiler reads

```
let () = Printf.printf "%d factorial is %d.\n" n fact(n)
```

as

```
let () = Printf.printf "%d factorial is %d.\n" n fact n
```

In other words, for the compiler the function `printf` 
is applied to 4 arguments: `"%d factorial is %d.\n"` ,`n`, `fact` and `n`.

But the format string, let's call it `fmt`, contains only two `%d` specifiers. Thus the compiler also knows that there `printf fmt` should takes two arguments and then returns unit. There is the discrepancy: `Printf.printf fmt n fact` is expected to returns a function that can be applied to the last argument `n` but it returns unit.
Or in other words,

> Type 'a -> 'b is not compatible with type unit

The earlier part of the error

> This expression has type
>            ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, 'a -> 'b)
>            CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt
>          but an expression was expected of type
>            ('a -> 'b, out_channel, unit, unit, unit, unit)
>            CamlinternalFormatBasics.fmt

is due to the fact that the type of format string is very flexible, and thus the typechecker only fails when it found out that it is not possible to print the format string and returns unit with the provided arguments.